# Provision personal OneDrive sites with powersell fails

Tags: powershell, onedrive

I have tried to pre provision personal **OneDrive** sites for users but it does not work. I have been following these links:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn800987.aspx
and
http://www.thinkscape.com/Provision-OneDrive-For-Business-Personal-Sites/

I have found that `CreatePersonalSiteEnqueueBulk` is **deprecated** and doesn't work anymore and that `Request-SPOPersonalSite` is the PowerShell alternative.

Here is the script I have been using:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminSiteUrl -Credential $credential

"Looking for personal site `$personalSiteUrl`"

Try
{
    Get-SPOSite $personalSiteUrl | Out-Null
}
Catch
{
    "Personal site not found. Creating it."
    #Create-PersonalSite

    Request-SPOPersonalSite -UserEmails @($email) -NoWait
}
```

Is there anyone that can see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you see when it fails?

Comment: I don´t get any error but the site is never created.